# How to ignore pep8 E128: continuation line under-indented for visual indent in Sublime Text

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, pep8

I am work on Python in sublime text editor. and I'm added [***PEP8 packages***](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-pep8).

I add 128 into following file `"pep8_ignore"`. After adding `128` and save.

> Preferences --> Package Setting --> SublimePythonIDE --> Seting User

```
{  
    "pep8_ignore": [128],
    "pep8_max_line_length": 100,
}
```

Then after not display any of ***PEP8 syntax error/warning***. What wrong I do?

How can I just ignore only **`128 - E128: continuation line under-indented for visual indent`** warning?

Comment: Try: `"pep8_ignore": ['E128']`

Answer (score 1):

you miss `E` for Error.
try this,

```
{  
    "pep8_ignore": ["E128"]
}
```

you can use `E` for Error and `W` for warning.
[link](http://outofmemoryblog.blogspot.in/2012/08/python-development-with-sublime-text-2.html)